# Android: Restrict editText entry after certain length

Tags: android-edittext, android-textwatcher

Hi I am using a text watcher on edit text
I want to restrict the number after certain length

```
suppose i want restrict length for  3
It should not allow 1234
but it should allow 123.(except dot(.) it should not allow any other character)
```

How can i do with TextWatcher.

Also tried to restrict all key entries except dot but not working

```
insideEdit.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                  if (keyCode == 46) // dot key code is 46
                    {

                        return false;
                    }else {

                        return true;
                    }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:maxLength="4"
```

inside `<EditText` tag